# How does quantum field theory pridict spin of electron?

Tags: electromagnetism, quantum-field-theory, electrons, quantum-spin

How does quantum field theory pridict the magnetic moment of electron (spin).
How does QFT interpret it?
What is the actual mechanism of origin of spin of fermions as well as bosons according to QFT?

Comment: By "product" you probably mean "describe" or "account for". Or are you asking for the history of the discovery of spin?

Comment: regarding the magnetic moment of spin, there are two separate important notions. First is spinor. The second is the gyromagnetic ratio (g-factor) and its deviation from 2 (predicted by the Dirac equation) that can be calculated using QFT